# Is there a "standard" height for towel bars in bathrooms?

Tags: bathroom

I'm hanging a towel bar on a wall in a newly-built bathroom (part of a major remodel). I would like to avoid placing the bar at an "awkward" height, but I'm not sure what the proper height would be. Is there a "standard" height?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's 48" for a bath towel.

I just put up new towel bars in my bathroom, and my method was to hold the bar up with a towel on it and have my wife tell me if it looked right. Just to be sure, she even acted like she was drying her hands to see if it felt right too. If I remember correctly, it came out to 46". (We're both short - the next owners can either complain about it or raise it themselves.)

Comment: Standard towel height in a new construction bathroom is 48".

Comment: Ahh, the wife standard. That is appropriate code in my house too.

Comment: Yes, standard height is 48" for adults. For kids room you can drop it a foot to 36". As an alternative for aesthetic reasons some people put it 12-16" from the top of the sink. 

In my house it also has to pass the wife test.

Answer (score 0):

We have a standard floor standing heated towel rail and it is approx 36" tall.

Also the towel rail on the side of our shower enclosure is 36" from the floor.